# svg files are being uploaded as "application/octet-stream" rather than "image/svg+xml"

Tags: svg, artifactory, mime-types, storybook

I am working on creating some stories using Storybook and publishing them on our server.

We currently build the static files using the command [build-storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/cli-options#build-storybook). When using the command [start-storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/cli-options#start-storybook) pointing to our static files that we built, everything works fine (ie. the svg icons are rendered fine).

The problem occurs when we transfer these static files to our server that we use to serve these static files.

We use the following script to do so:

```
find $name -type f -exec curl --fail --silent --show-error --output /dev/null -u CREDENTIALS --ftp-create-dirs -T {} ftp-server/{} \;
```

FYI... I am not exposing our credentials nor our FTP server in the above script. Also this script was taken from stackoverflow, it basically allows us to file transfer all our static files to our server.

The SVG icons are not loading in our stories when served from our server because their MIME type is set to `application/octet-stream` while we expect them to be `image/svg+xml`.

Before I ran the command to file transfer, I ensured that our SVG contains the right MIME type i.e. they are `image/svg+xml`. Also when serving those static files locally, the SVG renders fine so those svg initially contains the right MIME type. The problem happens during the file transfer, it somehow coverts ther MIME type from `image/svg+xml` to `application/octet-stream`.

I ensured we are using the right version of curl ie. version 7.75, so the svg content type should be [recognized](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/52fab72397687467650093c86e5479cb1d759042/lib/mime.c#L1759). Also I tried setting the content type through the headers ie `-H "Content-Type: image/svg+xml"` and I experience the same issue.

These are the logs when we FTP one of the svg:

```
12:39:07 > PUT ftp-server/static/media/svg-defs.79d8a5f2.svg HTTP/1.1
12:39:07 > Host: ftp-server
12:39:07 > Authorization: Basic ****
12:39:07 > User-Agent: curl/7.75.0
12:39:07 > Accept: */*
12:39:07 > Content-Type: image/svg+xml
12:39:07 > Content-Length: 77366
12:39:07 > Expect: 100-continue
12:39:07 > 
12:39:07 { [5 bytes data]
12:39:07 * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
12:39:07 < HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
12:39:07 } [5 bytes data]
12:39:07 * We are completely uploaded and fine
12:39:07 { [5 bytes data]
12:39:07 * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
12:39:07 < HTTP/1.1 201 Created
12:39:07 < Date: Thu, 27 May 2021 16:39:07 GMT
12:39:07 < Content-Type: application/****
12:39:07 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
12:39:07 < Connection: keep-alive
12:39:07 < Server: Artifactory/6.23.13
12:39:07 < Location: ftp-server/storybook/file-loader/static/media/svg-defs.79d8a5f2.svg
12:39:07 < 
12:39:07 { [835 bytes data]
12:39:07 
100 78189    0   823  100 {
12:39:07   "repo" : "****",
12:39:07   "path" : "/storybook/file-loader/static/media/svg-defs.79d8a5f2.svg",
12:39:07   "created" : "2021-05-27T16:39:07.759Z",
12:39:07   "createdBy" : "****",
12:39:07   "downloadUri" : "ftp-server/storybook/file-loader/static/media/svg-defs.79d8a5f2.svg",
12:39:07   "mimeType" : "application/octet-stream",
12:39:07   "size" : "77366",
12:39:07   "checksums" : {
12:39:07     "sha1" : "aec79d93b48becce503b590336027b040d604214",
12:39:07     "md5" : "83db7ccd983bafa823176c1ab7444d66",
12:39:07     "sha256" : "5feb84ec671e6332e3e2441563afa737545946e0c8b89438bc92935a493294b2"
12:39:07   },
12:39:07   "originalChecksums" : {
12:39:07     "sha256" : "5feb84ec671e6332e3e2441563afa737545946e0c8b89438bc92935a493294b2"
12:39:07   }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Thank you for educating me. I think it makes perfect sense now. Our server is artifactory and I was just reading this: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuration+Files#ConfigurationFiles-ModifyingConfigurationUsingtheUI. It seems that we just didn't have a type mapped to .svg extensions and hence it was defaulting to application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 1):

Marking this as resolved. This was a web server configuration on our side.

Edit:

We were hosting the static files in artifactory: https://jfrog.com/artifactory/

In artifactory, theres a file with a list of MIME types that it supports: `$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/mimetypes.xml`.

This file can be edited. It turned out that we did not have a MIME type mapped to `.svg` extensions so our svg files were being defaulted to `application/octet-stream`. Fix was just to edit that xml file to include the missing mime type.

For more info: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuration+Files#ConfigurationFiles-ModifyingConfigurationUsingtheRESTAPI